# JedisPooled connection - thread safety

Tags: redis, jedis

I'm using jedis client to interact with the Redis database. I'm using the code like the following as mentioned here in the [docs](https://github.com/redis/jedis#easier-way-of-using-connection-pool). I'm reusing the jedisPooled repeatedly in various places to add keys and values. I want to know whether the following method is thread-safe or not.

```
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPooled

val jedisPooled =  JedisPooled("localhost", 6379);

jedisPooled.set("enabled","true)
```

It is mentioned [here](https://github.com/redis/jedis#getting-started) that connection pools are thread-safe. But I encounter exceptions like
`java.net.SocketException` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error). I would appreciate it very much if someone could tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

JedisPooled is thread safe (as mentioned in [the doc you linked](https://github.com/redis/jedis#getting-started)).

`java.net.SocketException` is not due to thread safety issue. Look into the error on its own like [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error).

Comment: so if I create a Jedispooled instance one time and reuse it multiple times throughout the app, it won't fail?

Comment: No. but pool size should be good enough for your entire app

Comment: Are you referring to max connections? I'm not following what you mean by pool size.
I have changed my code to follow these instructions as [here](https://github.com/redis/jedis/wiki/Getting-started#using-jedis-in-a-multithreaded-environment) and now using jedispool and closing connections after the operation is done.

I have noticed that it does mitigate the errors I was facing.

Comment: Also I'm sorry but I didn't provide the complete error in my questions. It is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64859757/redis-clients-jedis-exceptions-jedisconnectionexception-java-net-socketexceptio) . Except for broken connections mine will be something like software aborted (write failed).

Comment: @Anandakrishnan Yes, by pool size I meant max connections.

Comment: hey sorry  for the late reply comment. This is just to be clear, I'm using the default `JedisPoolConfig` with 8 connections. Does this mean this is enough for my whole app.

Comment: I don't know the the full load of your whole app. So I can't say. You can start with it and increase the pool size later if necessary.